# can i use ionic components without ionic for a website?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

i've used and loved ionic in many mobile apps, but now as i'm building a web client for my app, i understand that ionic was not meant for desktop apps but my question is can i use its component in a regular angularjs - bootstrap 3 website ?

components i'm after are mostly the

1. pull to refresh and infinite scroll.
2. swipe list to show option buttons.
3. modals

i tried to start a new ionic project and add my custom css and js and just copy out www content

```
ionic start blank
```

but faced a problem as ionic keep changing my dom, and applying its own css that override mine. so i only want to extract the components and use regular angularjs.

is it possible ?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, as ionic is just AngularJS directives, optimized for mobile.

It had an easy way to add cordova items (ngCordova) but if you don't need those components and whish to build only a Browser project, just don't had that js file.

Even more, by doing ionic serve, you are indeed running your project into your browser.

Concerning your CSS issue, better paste your code into a codepen or jsfiddle to let us understand your issue.